# How do I change an uploaded image file's URL in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, url, thumbnails, gaia

We currently downloaded a Wordpress template from Themeforest called Gaia. It is a portfolio theme that allows you to upload portfolio items, and uses the featured posts section for the thumbnails on the main portfolio page. I have currently uploaded it on a subfolder of the website "/wordpress/".

Our problem is, whenever we upload a picture using the upload tool of the featured posts section, it formats the SRC of the uploaded image as:

`http://www.sitename.com/wordpress/http://www.sitename.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/gaia/images/thumbnail.jpg`

I have no idea why it includes the URL of the theme folder twice before the URL of the image file. Was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem that can point me to the direction of a solution.

Thank You in advance!
Seedorf.

Comment: There is a bug in the theme then. Ask Theme Forest to fix it.

Comment: I dont think its a bug. Its quite a popular theme and nobody has complained about it on their support site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. I guess its a bug then.